# "No locale data has been provided" regardless of what is passed in

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to use `intl` to do some formatting but no matter what I pass in as the locale, I always get the following error message:

> ReferenceError: No locale data has been provided for this object yet

I have tried the following:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-ZA', { minimumFractionDigits: percentDecimals });
```

as well as

```
new Intl.NumberFormat(['en-ZA'], { minimumFractionDigits: percentDecimals });
```

and I am not sure what else do.

I have added the package to the `package.json`

```
"intl": "latest"
```

and I do import it

```
import Intl from "intl";
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depending on the enviromnent you are running this code you might need to import locale data as well to polyfill locale

```
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en-ZA'
```

This import does side-effect that register `en-ZA` locale `IntlPolyfill.__addLocaleData({locale:"en-ZA",` when polyfill is required.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.

Comment: `import 'intl/locale-data/complete'` can be used to import everything, though this adds 1MB of bloat to your application, so it should only be used if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved by importing the "intl" at the top of the source code of the app.

In my case I was doing the import in `(i18n.ts)`.
`(i18n.ts)` is  where `i18next` is initialized. Then I have to move the import to the `App.tsx`.

```
// Polyfill Intl as it is not included in RN
import "intl";
```